# Create multiple frames in code behind in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to create multiple frames in code-behind, but when creating frames in loop and adding elements in content, only one frame has all elements and other frames are empty! why?

My code is:

```
private void searchResults_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    searchResults.IsVisible = false;

    Indexes Indexes = (Indexes)searchResults.SelectedItem;
    _viewModel.Items.Add(db.RequestToJson(Indexes.Index));

    searchbar.Text = string.Empty;




    StackLayout Words = new StackLayout();
    StackLayout WordDetail = new StackLayout();

    foreach (var dt in _viewModel.Items)
    {
        AddTextToLabel(nameof(dt.Word), dt.Word, WordDetail);
        var BaseLang = dt.BaseLang;
        AddTextToLabel(nameof(BaseLang.Meaning), BaseLang.Meaning, WordDetail);
        Words.Children.Add(new Frame { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("2196F3"), Padding = 5, HasShadow = false, Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 80, 10), Content = new StackLayout { Children = { WordDetail } } });
    }
    SearchResult.Content = Words;
    SearchResult.IsVisible = true;
}
private void AddTextToLabel(string title, string data, StackLayout worddetail)
{
    worddetail.Children.Add(new Label { Text = title + ":", FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White });
    worddetail.Children.Add(new Label { Text = data, TextColor = Color.White });
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Have you resolved your question?

Comment: yes  I solved it by moving the WordDetail in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the same instance of `WordDetail` in every iteration of the loop

instead, create a new instance each time

```
foreach (var dt in _viewModel.Items)
{
  StackLayout WordDetail = new StackLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your situation locally by copying your code.  I solved it by moving the WordDetail declaration inside the foreach like so:

```
StackLayout Words = new StackLayout();

foreach (var dt in _viewModel.Items)
{
    StackLayout WordDetail = new StackLayout();
    AddTextToLabel(nameof(dt.Word), dt.Word, WordDetail);
    var BaseLang = dt.BaseLang;
    AddTextToLabel(nameof(BaseLang.Meaning), BaseLang.Meaning, WordDetail);
    Words.Children.Add(new Frame { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("2196F3"), Padding = 5, HasShadow = false, Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 80, 10), Content = new StackLayout { Children = { WordDetail } } });
}
```